How to get the table name from Teradata QryLog for INSERT, UPDATE and Delete statement
I have a task to extract the Target tablename involved in INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operation in Teradata
for an example
if the SQL in dbc.Qrylog is below - I need TD.Employee alone;
INSERT into TD.Employee
SELECT * FROM TD.Employee_NEW
Is there a way to get this info in Teradata
I tried
select * from DBC.DBQLXMLTbl where XmltextInfo like '%LockOperation%'
But not all DML statement has LockOperation in it

DBQLObjTbl would have both tables (assuming OBJECT logging is enabled) but unfortunately there is no TypeOfUse value to indicate whether a table is source or target.

You may try this method:
select  A.LOGDATE, A.PROCID, A.QUERYID, 
  STATEMeNTTYPE,
  OBJECTDATABASENAME, OBJECTTABLENAME 
FROM PDCRDATA.DBQLOGTBL_HST A , PDCRDATA.DBQLOBJTBL_HST B 
WHERE A.LOGDATE = B.LOGDATE 
  AND A.PROCID = B.PROCID
  AND A.QUERYID = B.QUERYID 
  AND STATEMENTTYPE IN ( 'INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE')
  AND OBJECTTYPE = 'TAB'
  -- edit per request
  AND OBJECTDATABASENAME='TD'
  AND OBJECTTABLENAME='Employee'
;


Thanks for your Answer. This lists all the tables used in the SQL; I would like to get only the table we are Inserting, Deleting and Updating. In your SQL; if statement has Insert with select - It gives the table we insert and the table we select.

added a condition you were looking for
